# I need help finding out how to create a parametric equation given a point and where its orthogonal

Tags: calculus

The equation X(t)=**a**+t**d** is the parametric equation of a line through the point P:(2,−3,1). The parameter t represents distance from the point P, directed so that the i component of d is positive. We know that the line is orthogonal to the plane with equation 7x+8y−10z=−2.

**a**=_i+_j+_k

and

**b**=_i+_j+_k

I have already found the a which is the point given but i cant seem to figure out what is the vector that is orthogonal to the plane

Comment: If you consider i and j as vextors, I suggest writing them as **i** and **j**

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan please explain by what you mean? Ive found that the point P is the answer for a but **b** i cant seem to figure out

Comment: I mean that vectors are generally written in bold to avoid confusion. Like **a** = 3**i** +4 **j** while $a=5$. I am sorry I was not helpful but I was just giving tips on improving your question's readability.

Answer (score 0):

In the equation $$\alpha x+\beta y+\gamma z = \delta,$$ $$(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$$ are coordinates of a vector orthogonal to the plane.

The line is orthogonal to that plane.

Can you conclude now?